# Prisma generate not running properly on docker

Tags: docker, prisma

Hello all I am relatively new to docker and my backend is Node+express+redis+postgres+supabase.When i try to docker up i am getting error as

> tsx watch server/index.ts servers-api-1    | servers-api-1    |
> 9:26:03 AM [tsx] rerunning servers-api-1    |
> /usr/src/app/node_modules/.prisma/client/index.js:43 servers-api-1
> |     throw new Error( servers-api-1    |           ^ servers-api-1
> | servers-api-1    | Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet.
> Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again. servers-api-1
> | In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in
> https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues servers-api-1    |     at new
> PrismaClient (/usr/src/app/node_modules/.prisma/client/index.js:43:11)
> servers-api-1    |     at 
> (/usr/src/app/server/components/Usercomponent.ts:8:16) servers-api-1
> |     at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
> servers-api-1    |     at async ModuleLoader.import
> (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24) servers-api-1    |     at
> async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7) servers-api-1
> |     at async handleMainPromise
> (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12)`*

***My docker compose is ***

> FROM node:alpine
>
> WORKDIR /usr/src/app
>
> COPY package*.json ./
> RUN npm ci
>
> COPY . .
>
> RUN npx prisma generate
>
> CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

And my yml file is

> version: '3.9'
>
> services:
> redis:
> image: redis:latest
> restart: always
> volumes:
> redis_data:/data  # Use the defined volume
>
> api:
> build: . # build from Dockerfile xurrent
> ports:
> 4000:3000
> environment:
> PORT=3000
> DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:N4KLGkhGDKU0i4vC@db.yztrdeivgpjpnhvxtqwl.supabase.co:5432/postgres
> ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=c50267b906a652f
> REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET=R7pxEv0tLFVOtWoh
> depends_on:
> redis
>
> volumes:
> redis_data:
> external: false